# SQL query to show only completed GROUPED BY results

Tags: sql, visual-studio, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query which looks at results from a set of data in SQL Server 2008 R2. Essentially, a sample of people have been taking surveys a few times a day for a few months. In Visual Studio, I now want to write a report to show only those people who have never missed a survey for the entire period of time.

Let's say that the column structure is as follows:

```
ID | UserRef | ResultRef | Date  | Time
```

Where:

- `ID` is a unique identifier for the row
- `UserRef` is a unique identifier for each participant
- `ResultRef` indicated how the survey was completed (e.g. "A" would indicate that the survey was completed on time; "C" means that the participant missed the survey completely; "O" means that the survey was completed, but late; etc, etc, etc)
- `Date` and `Time` are self explanatory

What I want to find is all of the people that never missed a survey (i.e. only ever recorded a "A" in their `ResultRef`).

It is also worth bearing in mind that not all participants were invited to respond to all of the surveys: some will have been, but some will only have been invited to some of them.

I have been considering a `GROUP BY` query, but can't figure out the `WHERE` clause for this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is the surveys list come from? You have no survey id in your table structure, so how do you know the count of all survey the user should take???

Comment: Am I right that `It is also worth bearing in mind that not all participants were invited to respond to all of the surveys: some will have been, but some will only have been invited to some of them.` means that if the user has been invited to participate, there will be a row in this table ?

Comment: That is correct, @grahamj42

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE ResultRef = 'A' and UserRef NOT IN 
 (SELECT DISTINCT UserRef FROM yourTable 
  WHERE ResultRef != 'A')
```

Comment: you missed a "period of time", but in general +1 :)

Comment: Great job, @acutesoftware!